# Unzipping Files to Folders in SAS

Tags: directory, sas, unzip

I have a complicated folder structure that is in the following format:

```
 A --> New Jersey --> Construction --> 2020.10.27 --> Results.zip
 A --> New Jersey --> Materials    --> 2002.10.27 --> Results.zip
 A --> Pennsylvania --> Construction --> 2020.10.27 --> Results.zip
 A --> Pennsylvania --> Electrician --> 2020.10.27 --> Results.zip
```

As you can see, the sub-folders can have a lot of variation.  Is there a way to have SAS "enter" folder 'A' and then unzip all the Zip files, but save them to the sub-folder titled '2020.10.27'?  We want to make sure the unzipped csv file stays next to the zip file since all the files are names the same.

I know how to do this using a %MACRO statement with a lot of permutations, but wasn't sure if there is an easier way.

Any help would be appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: Please show the code you are currently using and explain why it is not what you want.  Provide some concrete examples of zip file names and what files are in them.  Do any of the files in the zips file have directory names attached?

Comment: Edited - the zip files are named 'Results.zip' and contain seven csv files each. I do not have any code as I do not know how to begin.  Typically I write Macros with permutations of the folder path. No, the zip files do not have directory names attached.

Comment: Is this in Windows or Linux? To prevent from having to write a lot of SAS code to search traverse each directory structure, you'd want to ideally unzip these recursively using the OS. You can have SAS call this code directly and save a lot of writing.

Comment: Windows - sorry for not specifying

Comment: Do you even need to extract the files in advance?  If you are going to read them from SAS just leave them in the ZIP files and use the ZIP engine on your INFILE or FILENAME statement.  `infile '...\Results.zip' zip member='Table1.csv' ....`

Comment: I cannot understand from your example what you want.  Do you want to find multiple ZIP files and export the files from them into a single folder? Will there be any name conflicts?  Do you only want to find zip files that are in folders named `2020.10.27`?  Do you want to create new folders named `2020.10.27` ?  If those date named folders already exist are they consistent in how the represent one digit month and day values?  If you want to create them to you want to use leading zeros in month/day numbers?

Comment: List files here https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.5&docsetId=mcrolref&docsetTarget=n0js70lrkxo6uvn1fl4a5aafnlgt.htm&locale=en and change it in the middle to unzip each file, rather than list it.

Comment: This post here asked the same question and has several answers. https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/Open-ZIP-file-to-import-batch-of-CSV-files-without-external/td-p/482075